# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'blog' of 'param' as it is undefined Strapi NextJS

Tags: json, next.js, strapi

I'm making a blog with NextJS and Strapi. I was making a comment functionality for my blogposts. But, I am getting 2 strange errors: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'blog' of 'param' as it is undefined.` and `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404`.
Here, is the blogpost code:

```html
import Image from "next/image";
import { api } from "../../../../http";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import SubmitComment from "@/components/SubmitComment";

const BlogPost = async ({ params: { slug } }: any) => {
  const { data } = await api.get(`/api/blogs?filters[slug]=${slug}&populate=*`);
  const blog = data.data[0]
  return (
    <div className="lg:max-w-screen-xl container mx-auto px-2">
      <div className="w-full py-10 bg-white min-h-screen">
        <div>
          <Image
            width={1000}
            height={800}
            alt="Image"
            className="mx-auto py-2 px-2"
            src={blog.attributes.main_image.data.attributes.url}
          />
          <div className="mx-10">
            <h1 className="text-5xl my-2 font-lato font-semibold">
              {blog.attributes.title}
            </h1>
            <ReactMarkdown
              className="my-2 markdown"
              children={blog.attributes.body}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full my-2 py-10 bg-white">
        <SubmitComment blog={blog} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogPost;
```

As in nextjs 13 useState is used to be in client side components, I made the comment component separately. This is the code:

```html
"use client"

import { useState } from "react";
import { api } from "../../http";

const SubmitComment = async ({blog}:any) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('')
  const [comment, setComment] = useState<string>('')
  const res = await api.post('/api/comments', {
    name,
    email_id: email,
    comment,
    blog: blog.id
  })
  console.log(res)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-2">
        <input
          type="name"
          name="name"
          className="ml-2 bg-gray-100 h-8 rounded-full px-2 text-lg"
          placeholder="Your name"
          onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.name)}}
        />
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          className="mr-2 bg-gray-100 h-8 rounded-full px-2 text-lg"
          placeholder="Your Email ID"
          onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.name)}}
        />
        <textarea
          className="mx-2 lg:col-span-2 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg px-2 text-lg"
          placeholder="Comment"
          rows={5}
          onChange={(e)=>{setComment(e.target.name)}}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center my-2">
        <button type="submit" className="button">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubmitComment;
```

Here is the actual json blogpost response:

```html
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "Why do Red Giants expand ?",
        "body": "Red giants expand because of a change in the balance of forces within the star. When a star is on the main sequence, it is fusing hydrogen in its core. This fusion reaction produces a lot of energy, which keeps the star's core hot and prevents it from collapsing.\n\nHowever, once the star's core runs out of hydrogen, the fusion reaction stops. This causes the core to cool and contract. As the core contracts, it becomes denser and hotter. This heat causes the outer layers of the star to expand.\n\nThe expansion of the outer layers is caused by a combination of factors. First, the heat from the contracting core causes the gas in the outer layers to expand. Second, the gravity of the star is not strong enough to hold the outer layers in place, so they expand.\n\nThe expansion of the outer layers causes the star to become much larger and brighter. This is why red giants are so much larger and brighter than main sequence stars.\n\nThe expansion of red giants is a temporary phase in the life of a star. Eventually, the outer layers of the star will be ejected into space, leaving behind a white dwarf or a neutron star.\n\n**Here is a summary of the reasons why red giants expand:**\n\n- The core of the star contracts and becomes denser, which releases heat.\n- The heat from the contracting core causes the outer layers of the star to expand.\n- The gravity of the star is not strong enough to hold the outer layers in place, so they expand.\n- The expansion of red giants is a fascinating phenomenon that helps us to understand the life cycle of stars. It is also a reminder that even the most stable stars are constantly changing and evolving.\n\n",
        "slug": "why-does-red-giants-expand",
        "createdAt": "2023-06-16T12:11:54.069Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-06-17T11:13:30.105Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-06-16T14:21:48.839Z",
        "main_image": {
          "data": {
            "id": 3,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "scientists-witness-red-giant-star-explode-real-time-first-time-ever.jpg",
              "alternativeText": null,
              "caption": null,
              "width": 784,
              "height": 441,
              "formats": {
                "small": {
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1686925296/small_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035.jpg",
                  "hash": "small_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "name": "small_scientists-witness-red-giant-star-explode-real-time-first-time-ever.jpg",
                  "path": null,
                  "size": 31.72,
                  "width": 500,
                  "height": 281,
                  "provider_metadata": {
                    "public_id": "small_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                    "resource_type": "image"
                  }
                },
                "medium": {
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1686925296/medium_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035.jpg",
                  "hash": "medium_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "name": "medium_scientists-witness-red-giant-star-explode-real-time-first-time-ever.jpg",
                  "path": null,
                  "size": 62.85,
                  "width": 750,
                  "height": 422,
                  "provider_metadata": {
                    "public_id": "medium_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                    "resource_type": "image"
                  }
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                  "ext": ".jpg",
                  "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1686925296/thumbnail_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035.jpg",
                  "hash": "thumbnail_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                  "mime": "image/jpeg",
                  "name": "thumbnail_scientists-witness-red-giant-star-explode-real-time-first-time-ever.jpg",
                  "path": null,
                  "size": 8.04,
                  "width": 245,
                  "height": 138,
                  "provider_metadata": {
                    "public_id": "thumbnail_scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                    "resource_type": "image"
                  }
                }
              },
              "hash": "scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
              "ext": ".jpg",
              "mime": "image/jpeg",
              "size": 70.11,
              "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/djpxkfscg/image/upload/v1686925296/scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035.jpg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "cloudinary",
              "provider_metadata": {
                "public_id": "scientists_witness_red_giant_star_explode_real_time_first_time_ever_ef95780035",
                "resource_type": "image"
              },
              "createdAt": "2023-06-16T14:21:36.761Z",
              "updatedAt": "2023-06-16T14:21:41.736Z"
            }
          }
        },
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "attributes": {
                "name": "Ritarpan Ghosh",
                "email_id": "ritarpanghosh29@gmail.com",
                "comment": "HELOO",
                "createdAt": "2023-06-17T11:59:50.333Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-06-17T11:59:50.996Z",
                "publishedAt": "2023-06-17T11:59:50.987Z"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the blog object to SubmitComment here

```
        <SubmitComment blog={blog} />
```

Is not needed destructure blog on the parameters, change for

```
const SubmitComment = async (blog:any) => {
```

I hope this helped you

Comment: Now this is the error: 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Comment: well that error is for a null useState, try to make a console.log of your useState, but maybe is in other file because these doesn't call any property of useState.
Also check the error, should tell you in which part of your code is the problem.